# Is it possible to train a unit while it is upgrading in the laboratory?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have put dragons to upgrade to level 3 in the laboratory. Is it possible to train dragons during this time?

Comment: You didn't try training them?

Comment: @Jerry, this kinda upgrade will take something like 3 days in game. If you were to find it was a waste of time training some dragons at level 2, as you'd then need to retrain them for level 3 after the lab completes, you'd be annoyed. The question is valid.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I believe [this edit of yours](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/145497) changes what OP was asking about

Comment: The user wanted to know how the act of upgrading effects currently training units..... or at least thats how I read it?

Comment: @djsmiley2k Uhh, the trained lv2 dragons automatically becomes lv3 once your lab completes the upgrade. If you have never tried it, then do it. It is actually something that a player can take advantage of. I usually put lots of troops that is about to be upgraded in my barracks (they are being trained by the way, this is what the question is really about) and take me resources. After upgrade, I remove them from the barracks (I don't let them come out) and make a profit in resources because I am taking back higher level troops. Never tried that either? Well, do it.

Comment: I did it with the most effective unit- Wallbreakers. Gained about 5000 elixir

Comment: @Jerry, i find it unnecessary to put a troop in, and take it out, especially after the troop upgraded.The more the marrier is all i'm saying. You can get more loot that way :)

Comment: @Jesusfreaks How does 'the more the merrier' link to putting a troop in and take it out? How does *not* putting troops in barracks and taking them out after they are upgraded give you *more* loot?

Comment: I've reverted this question to a previous edit as [other users in chat seem to agree with me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23231771#23231771) that [this edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/145497) deviates from the original intent of the post. This is also to avoid making this question a duplicate of [Will already existing troops upgrade when their respective laboratory research finishes?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/215768/4797)

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, you can train a unit even if it is currently upgrading in the laboratory.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,

Once the unit is upgraded in the lab, *ALL* of those unit will become the new level.

Comment: also, if you queue a load of troops in your barracks which are being upgraded in the lab (with full camps), once the lab upgrade is completed, you can cancel the queued troops and receive a refund for the higher level troop cost! Free Elixir!

Answer (score 0):

***Yes***, you can train the unit even if it is upgrading. When the dragons are done upgrading, all the dragons in your army camp and barracks training will level up.

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer your question, yes.Even as a unit is upgrading, you have the authorization to train in your barracks. However, until the upgrade is complete you will only have the current troop level.Once the upgrade is complete,you have your troop upgraded and you will be able to use it at that level.